# Redirect file data to python in cmd (poor windows interaction?)

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, cmd

Why does the following code print nothing (from command line - cmd.exe):

```
python -c "import sys;print(sys.stdin.read())" < C:\temp\tt.txt
```

Windows 10, everything is normal. native python 3.9 . The file has data...

BTW, please don't suggest alternative solutions like `type` and pipe. I want to understand what kills it, and this kind of thing is involved in the use case of filtering in vim.

Comment: Works fine in the online sandbox at https://replit.com/@CharlesDuffy2/SecretSaddlebrownConversion#main.sh

Comment: That is not the sort of things you want to try in a sandbox I think. The sandbox is different than windows.

Comment: How exactly was this copy of Python installed? Is it a Cygwin-native Python? A WSL-provided executable? A Windows-native Python? ...?

Comment: Right, but many (most?) of us aren't Windows developers. I don't _have_ a copy of Windows I can test this on, and also don't want one. :)

Comment: A windows native

Comment: Try add a `, flush=True)` to the `print()` call.

Comment: What happens, if anything, when you run the code?  Does it block on input?  Does it return to the command prompt immediately?  Does it hang forever?

Comment: I get an empty line and it exists @JohnGordon

Comment: flush=True changed nothing